# Return false does not work on a second onclick toggle event

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a toggle function. When it's first fired the link doesn't activate because of the return false - this is good.

But after it's toggled the link does fire! I need it not too. Any help please?

```
function viewSHowHide() {

if (document.getElementById("viewSHowHide").innerHTML=="Hide Question") {
document.getElementById("viewSHowHide").innerHTML="View Question";
HideQ();

} else {
document.getElementById("viewSHowHide").innerHTML="Hide Question";
viewQ();
}

}
```

HTML

```
<a title="View Question" id="viewSHowHide" onclick="viewSHowHide(); return false" href="">View Question</a>
```

Comment: Check your browser's console (Ctrl+Shift+J) for any errors

Comment: what are `HideQ` and `ViewQ` doing? Just commenting them out works properly in my system. Can you post them, May be those methods have some problem.

Comment: @Moazzam Khan I am a novice. I am doing a Tarot reading app. It's html with JS functionality. When viewQ() is fired it changes a div to display a text from a previously stored cookie. When hideQ() is fired the div is hidden again. The page doesn't jump when the onclick event is first clicked (view question) but does jump when clicked again (hide question). It's weird!

Comment: @koala_dev No errors in my console:)

Comment: @Hannah try using `href="javascript:void(0)"`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of what your trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/fnd9C/

I switched it over to a `<span>` so I didn't have to fight what the link wants to do by default, and cleaned up the code a little bit.

HTML:

```
<span title="View Question" id="viewSHowHide" onclick="viewSHowHide();">View Question</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
viewSHowHide = function(){
    var showHide=document.getElementById("viewSHowHide");
    if (showHide.innerHTML=="Hide Question") {
        showHide.innerHTML="View Question";
        HideQ();
    } else {
        showHide.innerHTML="Hide Question";
        viewQ();
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have it down but it doesn't work. Chrome seems to ignore return false the second time the same onclick event has been clicked.

Comment: Did you try the jsfiddle? I'm not using the return false, because I switch it to a span. Why fight the browsers default behavior if you don't have to? Your using an `<a>` but its not a link.

Comment: You're right, I see why you changed it to span now! It's strange that something so simple doesn't work. I have finally rewrote the whole thing differently and now works. I should not have adapted my original toggle script. I should have just wrote it from scratch in the first place. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try using `href="javascript:void(0)"` as in

```
<a title="View Question" id="viewSHowHide" onclick="viewSHowHide(); return false" href="javascript:void(0)">View Question</a>
```

Comment: This fires the viewQ event by does not execute the toggle and consequently the hide() event.

Comment: Sorry I could not get you, Your problem was when you click on the `<a>` tag, your page gets reloaded. Does my answer solve it? And after this do you get any other problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think...

**All You Need**

```
if (event.preventDefault) { //check if browser supports preventDefault
    event.preventDefault();
} else { //if no support -> IE lte 8
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

or shorthand:
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

wrap it in a function for faster usage e.g. :

```
<a href="#something" onclick="prevent();">click prevent</a>

<script>
prevent = function() { // in this case no need to pass 'event'
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    console.log('event prevented :)');
}
</script>
```

**Why**
all modern browsers support event.preventDefault, but IE supports it from v9
for older IE versions (this is what e.g. jQuery uses) you hook up to the returnValue of an event.

*jQuery Code for reference

```
jQuery.Event.prototype = {
[...]
preventDefault: function() {
    var e = this.originalEvent;

    this.isDefaultPrevented = returnTrue;
    if ( !e ) {
        return;
    }

    // If preventDefault exists, run it on the original event
    if ( e.preventDefault ) {
        e.preventDefault();

    // Support: IE
    // Otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
},
[...]
```

I hope i didn't make any mistakes here ;)
Good Luck...